# How to check localstorage in data Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I made todolist using Vue js and localstorage(LS). Everything is ok but when I'm trying run it in a different browser where LS is free I've got an error `Cannot read property 'items' of null"`. I have to check LS before work with it, but I'm reading LS in Data where I can't check LS.

Part of my code:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '.row',
data:{
    cap:undefined,
    ti:undefined,

    forLS:{
        items:[]
    },
    count:-1,
    forLS:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allData")),
    count:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count"))
    }
```

I tried to read LS in a function but I can't run it in Data.
All code [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/vr9ye0vb/)
I really don't know how to solve this problem. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need a fallback in case the localStorage is empty :

```
{
    el: '.row',
    data:{
        cap:undefined,
        ti:undefined,
        forLS:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("allData") || '{ "items":[] }'),
        count:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("count") || '-1' )
}
```

Actually here is a [working fork](https://jsfiddle.net/kz0yvskv/) of your fiddle